# How to get frequency band in which device getting signal from operator?

Tags: networking, mobile-network

I have to find the frequency in which device is working currently. Ex: My device is connected with ABC network which is 4G and run on 2100MHz or 1800MHz, So I want to know the frequency(i.e. 2100MHz or 1800MHz).

Please share your experience Which will help me to find the frequency band. But guys I don't wanna to know the network type. Is there any way by using reflection Please share.

Comment: As it is a cell phone: Call the provider (hotline) and ask? I'm not aware of any settings page or app to show that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Izzy But I am looking for the code, Is there any way via code so that I can fetch this information.

Answer (score -1):

Dial `*#*#4636#*#*` then select phone information.

Comment: Is the frequency listed there? Could you please [edit] your answer and include a screenshot, maybe? I couldn't find that detail on my devices.